# xcache Admin Page is Showing Cache ONLY For Current User (CPanel)

Tags: php, cpanel, xcache

I have a brand spanking new cPanel server. cPanel recently added xcache functionality right into EasyApache, so I built xcache with fastCGI using easyapache. It seems to work, except that whatever account I put the admin pages of xcache on, that's the only account that xcache admin is showing caching info for. This has me worried that it's somehow setup to run a separate 32MB cache for each user (bad news...).

Can anyone shed some light on this behavior? Is this normal and some sort of security mechanism to keep users from viewing each other's caches? Is one 32MB cache being created or one for each user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have suExec enabled, then yes, you have a separate 32MB cache for each user. This is because PHP runs with the UID of the user when suExec is enabled.

For more information, see:

- http://xcache.lighttpd.net/ticket/206
- https://helpdesk.wiredtree.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1663

Comment: Thanks Josh, wow that's a good thing to catch then. On that note, I don't suppose if you know whether that also means a PHP process hangs around indefinitely for each user? I've got a few accounts in my testing setup now, and there are big (135MB!!!) PHP processes just hanging out under each user. Do they ever get killed? Is there a cap?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I believe they will. That's how FastCGI works: it keeps a pool of PHP processes open and ready. I voted to migrate your question to ServerFault where you'll get more expert answers. I personally use FastCGI without suexec.

Comment: Ah shoot, that would have made more sense to post. Thanks for your help Josh, I'm diving deeper into it and I believe you are right.